# How to reset linux centOS 6.0 keyboard shortcuts with custom changes to default one?

Tags: linux, centos, keyboard-shortcuts, gedit

On Single Desktop Environment....

I created some custom shortcuts, but currently I want to revert all the changes to default settings (which having no custom changes).

Example: created like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> = new terminal and later changed it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

so here, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> is overridden with some conflicts. Where gedit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for opening a new document is affected (not working at all).

I found some related questions on this, but none resolved my purpose.

Actually, if there are no ways to reset entire keyboard shortcut keys in CentOS, please suggest a way to rectify <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to work fine for `gedit` again?

Comment: keyboard shortcuts are usually handled by the desktop environment (in case you are using a desktop environment, which is unclear from your question). given that you can have multiple desktop environments on a `centOS` system, you need to be more specific.

Comment: After complete reboot, gedit conflicts for creating new document is gone and working fine now. Got fixed automatically. Now as per the initial question, way for reverting entire custom shortcut changes to default didn't get any method.

Answer (score 0):

Click on System > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts to launch the application and view the preconfigured shortcuts.